# Ubuntu 19.10 + fresh install + GoXLR audio skipping

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a USB Audio DAC called a GoXLR that plugs in via USB. It seemed to work out of the box except every 3-4 seconds the audio cuts out for second. I've tried both Rhythmbox and Firefox.

I've attempted to fix this by following the steps listed here with no change : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Choppy/distorted_sound